# CSharpScript uses incompatible internal type representations at every external class instantiation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following script to call the CSharpScript engine;

https://blog.jayway.com/2015/05/09/using-roslyn-to-build-a-simple-c-interactive-script-engine/

I have a namespace Test:

```
  namespace Test {
     class B() {
     }

  }
```

And I add to the options of the CSharpScriptEngine;

```
options = ScriptOptions.Default
            .WithReferences(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AddImports("Test")
```

Now I execute the following code:

```
 class A {}
 var a1 = new A(); 
 var a2 = new A(); 
 a1==a2

 False
```

That is correct, now:

```
 var b1 = new B();
 var b2 = new B();
 b1 == b2

 Error in code 'b1 == b2':  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'B' and 'B'



 b1.GetType()==b2.GetType()

 True
```

Using any external class, I cannot get two instances which are created within the CSharpScript engine that are seen by C# as being of the same Type.

Edit3, another lovely example:

```
> string Hello(B world) { return world.ToString(); }

> Hello(new B())

Error in code 'Hello(new B())':  Argument 1  cannot convert from 'Test.B [C \Users\User\Projects\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Test.dll]' to 'Test.B [Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
```

Edit1, formatted comment answer:

```
> var b1 = new B();

> var b2 = new B();

> b1.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName 

Test.B, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> b2.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName

Test.B, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> b1==b2
Error in code 'b1==b2':  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'B' and 'B'
```

Edit2, comment answer with full namespace:

```
> new B() == new B()
False

> new Test.B() == new Test.B()
False

> var b1 = new Test.B();
> var b2 = new Test.B();
> b1==b2
Error in code 'b1==b2':  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'B' and 'B'
```

Edit4, formatted code to reproduce with a failing and succeeding example of the same code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

namespace Test
{
    public class B
    {

    }
    public class CSharpScriptEngine
    {
        private static ScriptState<object> scriptState = null;

        static ScriptOptions options;

        public static void Init()
        {
            options = ScriptOptions.Default
                .WithReferences(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())

                .AddImports("Test")

                ;
        }
        public static object Execute(string code)
        {
            try
            {


                scriptState = scriptState == null
                    ? CSharpScript.RunAsync(code, options).Result
                    : scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(code, options).Result;


                if (scriptState.ReturnValue != null
                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptState.ReturnValue.ToString()))
                {
                    return scriptState.ReturnValue;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                string str = e.Message;
                if (str.Contains(": error CS"))
                {
                    str = string.Join(' ', str.Split(':').Skip(2).ToArray());
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine($"Error in code '{code}': {str}");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSharpScriptEngine.Init(); 
            var code = @"
                var b1 = new B(); 
                var b2 = new B(); 
                b1 == b2

            ";

            // -> SUCCEEDS! 
            Console.WriteLine(CSharpScriptEngine.Execute(code)?.ToString());

            // -> FAILS!
            code.Split('\n').Select(s => CSharpScriptEngine.Execute(s)).Where(s => s != null).ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s)); 

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `new Test.B()`?

Comment: Print b1.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName and b2.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName and see if they are different.

Comment: > var b1 = new B();

> var b2 = new B();

> b1.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName 

Test.B, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> b2.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName

Test.B, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> b1==b2
Error in code 'b1==b2':  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'B' and 'B'

Comment: See my changed question for better formatting.

Comment: Edit3 might give more insights as that's the only way I get something 'different' out of the 2 types. Although in any other way they are exactly the same (and b1.GetType()==b2.GetType()==true).

Comment: Can you post full (minimal) code of application to reproduce?

Comment: Thanks Evk, by creating a minimal functional version, I found out the difference between most examples on the web and my example. I am trying to make a repl and that is where it happens. I found a repl example on github which exhibits the same issue. Hopefully someone here knows the (undoubtfully) trivial solution to this. See the code to reproduce in Edit4.

Comment: This may be a Roslyn bug: a similar issue is being looked at: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23123